# Parent link in mobile nav not clickable in JointsWP

Tags: php, mobile, menu, submenu

I'm currently using JointsWP for a WordPress theme. I'm running into an issue where the parent links in my dropdown menu are not clickable.

I searched the Foundation forums and found [this thread](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/809-top-bar-parent-links) that I thought would be helpful. It mentions adding `data-options="mobile_show_parent_link: true"` to the nav class top-bar.

JointsWP doesn't use the `nav` tag for it's menu, but I did add it where I thought it should be, which is the `ul` wrapper in the /assets/functions/menu.php file like so:

```
// The Top Menu
function joints_top_nav() {
 wp_nav_menu(array(
    'container' => false,                           // Remove nav container
    'menu_class' => 'vertical medium-horizontal menu',       // Adding custom nav class
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s" data-options="mobile_show_parent_link: true" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown">%3$s</ul>',
    'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // Where it's located in the theme
    'depth' => 5,                                   // Limit the depth of the nav
    'fallback_cb' => false,                         // Fallback function (see below)
    'walker' => new Topbar_Menu_Walker()
));
} /* End Top Menu */
```

However, this is not working.

I've also tried:

`data-options="is_hover: false"`

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the top parent link clickable when the submenu is expanded in mobile for JointsWP?

Thanks!